# Multi-table select, limiting number of results

Tags: sql

So let's say you had a query to retrieve stats on all baseball players in a db that has constantly updating stats such as walks, home runs, etc, such as:

```
SELECT pl.player_name, pl.player_number, bat.at_bats, pit.era 
FROM players pl
LEFT JOIN batting bat ON pl.player_id = bat.player_id
LEFT JOIN pitching pit ON pl.player_id = pit.player_id
```

Now say you also wanted to pull stats from another table, say a salaries table, but you wanted to only pull the most recent salary, so something like:

```
SELECT pl.player_name, pl.player_number, bat.at_bats, pit.era, sal.salary
FROM players pl
LEFT JOIN batting bat ON pl.player_id = bat.player_id
LEFT JOIN pitching pit ON pl.player_id = pit.player_id
LEFT JOIN salaries sal ON pl.player_id = sal.player_id
```

But you only want to get their most recent salary number for each player. How would you combine all of these? Hopefully I explained that clearly.

Comment: Show table schema, example data, and desired results. For instance, how do we know what "most recent" means if it's not indicated?

Comment: Show us your attempt and tell us why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT pl.player_name, pl.player_number, bat.at_bats, pit.era, s.salary
FROM players pl
LEFT JOIN batting bat ON pl.player_id = bat.player_id
LEFT JOIN pitching pit ON pl.player_id = pit.player_id
cross apply (select top 1 * from salaries sal where pl.player_id = sal.player_id order by 
              sal.SalaryDate desc) s
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you. I wasn't familiar with CROSS APPLY.

Comment: cross apply and outer apply are very very useful.I really enjoy working it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a fun bit of code in this document (page 6 - it's written for SAS, but since SAS uses ANSI SQL the code works with all SQL systems): https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/0930-2017.pdf

For your application, it would look something like this (not positive, but this should be close):

```
SELECT pl.player_name, pl.player_number, bat.at_bats, pit.era, sal.salary
FROM players pl
LEFT JOIN batting bat ON pl.player_id = bat.player_id
LEFT JOIN pitching pit ON pl.player_id = pit.player_id
LEFT JOIN (
    select salary,
        player_id
    from salaries sal1
    where salDate = (
                    select max(salDate)
                    from salaries sal2
                    where sal1.player_id = sal2.player_id
                   )
           ) as sal ON pl.player_id = sal.player_id
```

A bit of a pain in this case since you need 2 subqueries to do it as you describe. I would probably join all the salaries in a CTE and then do the max() self join to select the most recent as the final select.

Comment: They want the most recent salary, not the minimal salary the player has ever had...

Comment: Right, I did mess that up. I was going on the fields they added and forgot the question! You'd instead use some undefined date field and match on that, selecting the appropriate salary. I'll update the code.

Comment: Better, but still: `min` will identify the oldest date, and `date` can't be used (unescaped) as an identifier because it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Argh - definitely right. Thanks for pointing out all those errors; I normally just rely on the submit then fix errors method, but guess-and-check isn't really the most efficient way to do anything...